# Unable to run jupyter notebook

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

cannot open juypter notebook from terminal or anaconda app

terminal shows notebook as already open, running

- uninstall/reinstall (x3) hasn’t fixed it
- cannot access notebook from any ports, or 127.0.0.1
- upgrading pyzmq doesn’t resolve the issue
- removing and reinstalling pyzmq doesn’t resolve the issue

using windows 10

any sugggestions much appreciated, thank you